# Jquery image scroll problem

Tags: jquery, image, scroll

I'm using a "image scroll jquery," script I found via Google (1st or 2nd result "nettuts) and I have hacked together the following [this](http://techavid.com/imageScroller/imageScroller.html)

When the image scroll begins it starts all the way to the right.  Upon page load the aston martin image (1st image seen) should start the scroll on the left side and not the far right because as you see when the scroll is done scrolling there is a long stretch of no images scrolling.

Anyone have any suggestions on how I can have the scroll begin all the way to the left and in turn eliminating the long stretch of nothing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your javascript:

```
//set initial position and class based on direction
$("div#container").css("left", 0).addClass("rtl") : $("div#container").css("left", 0 - $("div#container").width()).addClass("ltr") ;
```

You are just replacing:

```
$("div#viewer").width()
```

With 0

Comment: Hi Thanks Adam.  That move it to the left; awesome!  Still trying to create a carousel effect.  Again thnx for the tip and any other suggestions!